# Apply keyEvent to a method

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, keyevent

I created this method:

```
public void comboS() {

    ResultSet rset = null;
    String sch = ((JTextField) ComboItemName.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();
    try {
        rset = new JDBC.DB().getData("SELECT * FROM item_reg WHERE id LIKE '" + sch + "%';");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    ComboItemName.removeAllItems();
    try {
        while (rset.next()) {
            String item = rset.getString("id");
            ComboItemName.addItem(item);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(jfilechooser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(sch);
    ComboItemName.setSelectedItem(null);
    ComboItemName.setPopupVisible(true);
    ((JTextField) ComboItemName.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setText(sch);

}
```

I call this method in actionPerformed of the JComboBox(ComboItemName)..When I type HDD and hit enter it shows all the ids of hard disks in database..But I want this to be appear while I typing HDD.I think for that a keyEvent should be apply to the method like this.

```
public void comboS(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
```

But I don't know how to call this method and where in combo box.give me some help for this.thanks.
Like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) on your editor component for that purposes, here is example with that:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Example extends JFrame {


    public Example() {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"1","2"});
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        ((JTextComponent)comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                validateHDD(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                validateHDD(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                validateHDD(arg0);
            }

            private void validateHDD(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String text = arg0.getDocument().getText(0, arg0.getDocument().getLength());
                    if(text.equals("HDD")){
                        System.out.println("HDD entered");
                        //call your method here
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        add(comboBox);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Example frame = new Example();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`validateHDD` validate if you entered HDD into editor of `JComboBox`, and then executes some logic if it is true.

Comment: not exactly HDD any id from database HDD for hard disk MON for monitor

Answer (score 1):

To attach a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) on a ComboBox, first of all your Combo must be editable.

```
    jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
```

Then just attach the KeyListener like this:

```
    jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " KEY_TYPED DETECTED. \n");
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " KEY_PRESS DETECTED. \n");
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " KEY_RELEASE DETECTED. \n");
        }
    });
```

[image]

As simple as that :)

**UPDATE**

As @alex2410 spotted, it would be best to implement this with [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead. Here is how to:

```
    final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Combo Value is: " + tc.getText() + " . \n");
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Combo Value is: " + tc.getText() + " . \n");
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Combo Value is: " + tc.getText() + " . \n");
        }
    });
```

[image]

As a side note, please stick to [Java code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: Ok then where this call..jcombobox actionPerformed or any event of combobox

Comment: you will attach the KeyListener after you initialize your Combo

Comment: -1... `KeyListener` it's low level implementation, instead of that you need to use `DocumentListener` on editor component.

Comment: As I can tell from your code, you should add the Key listener after the call `ComboBox ComboItemName  = new ComboBox();`. If you are doing it in NetBeans, then add this code in the Constructor after the `initComponents();` method by replacing `jComboBox1` with `ComboItemName`

Comment: But You do all these thing in constructor..but my application where I create combo box with drag and drop..in JSP what is the solution

Comment: sorry sorry not JSP Swing program